# Does open SUSE include NTP server?

Tags: linux, opensuse

I want to setup a NTP server on open SUSE 11.1.

But I don't know whether it has been supported in the system, or it needs me to install a software manually.

If not, is there any kind of open source or free ware I can use？

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, NTP both client and server are part of the distro as long as you select them during installation.

Answer (score 0):

xntpd is in all Linux distributions I'm aware of, is free, open source, and exceedingly common.  That is the one you'll want.  I admit to not having checked SuSE recently.

Comment: I know there is a /etc/init.d/ntp on openSUSE.
But I think it is a NTP client, which uses other sources to synchronize the local time.

What I want is a NTP server, is it supported as well?
Thanks.

Comment: ntp should be a client and a server (same program).  Both client and server require the software to perform the same function, and to run all-the-time, and to support the same protocols.  Both tools to do NTP that I'm aware of (xntpd and ntp, (possibly the same?)) are both client and server.

Comment: There is no NTP client.  The NTP server works as a client to its sources (defined as servers in the config file), and a server to hosts which treat it as a server.  Hosts can be configured as peers in which case the act as both client and server to the peer.   Access restrictions can be configured to prevent the a host from providing time to other hosts.

Some tools such as ntpdate use NTP servers a time source, but don't offer full NTP functionality, so I dont consider them clients.

Comment: What exactly is the distinction between a client and a server in your mind?  An NTP "server" that has no connections to any machines at an equal or higher stratum is, in what way, a server?  In what way is 'ntpdate' not a client?  To what end do you make this server/client distinction?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/NTP
It's for Gentoo, but configuration files for ntp are same. ntp can act both as a client and a server. You just need to set it up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but you need the yast module for a GUI probably called yast2-ntp